# Conversion Tracking Extract empty

Tags: marketing-cloud, conversion, tracking-extract

I am trying to do the Tracking Extract (Conversions) from Salesforce Marketing Cloud. I'm fine with the process of doing it, but when it falls into the FTP the data is empty. Has anyone else encountered this problem or has any advice why this is happening? I can see the conversions in Email Studio Tracking tab per send but I want to see all sends in the past 7 or 30 days.

[image: Data Extract]

Comment: I have seen that with Campaign ID and had to raise a ticket to Salesforce. I think that's your best bet

Comment: If you click into conversions within tracking does it have data/values? are you passing the data node in the xml call?

Comment: @EazyE Yes - we can see conversions in the email send reports and you can click into them and see product and customer data. The data note is also being passed in the xml call.

Comment: @Maneesh Salesforce issue, thanks for that!